# Why my contact form in html,php is not working?

Tags: php, send

Hi I am facing a problem with my contact form I didn't receive any mails and I don't know why ..

Here is my php code is there any thing wrong

```
 <?php
$name=$_POST ['name'];
$mobileno=$_POST ['mobileno'];
$email=$_POST ['email'];
$message=$_POST ['message'];

$to = 'any mail.com';
$subject = ' Message from your Webite';
$msg = " Your name : $name\n"; 
$msg .= " Your Mobile No. : $mobileno\n"; 
$msg .= " Your email: $email\n" ;
$msg .= " Your Message: $message";

mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

echo ' Thank You <br/>';
echo ' Your name ' . $name . '<br>';
echo ' Your email ' . $email . '<br>';
echo ' Your Mobile No. ' . $mobileno . '<br>';
echo ' Your Message ' . $message . '<br>';

?>

<br /><br />
 Here is the result from $msg: <br /><br />
 <?php 

 echo $msg;

 ?>
```

My HTML Code I have edited the code several times but nothing happened

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="justsend.php">

  <p>

    <label for="mobileno">your mobile</label>

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno">

    <label for="name"><br>
      your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">your email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="message">your message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="send">send msg</label>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your global `$_POST` needs to have the spaces removed.
`$name=$_POST ['name'];` should be `$name=$_POST['name'];`

Comment: Update your new code.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: have you tried with `if(mail(TO, SUBJECT, MSG, ....etc...)) {echo SUCCESS} ELSE { echo FAIL }` ? You're actually better off using something like PHPMailer

Comment: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Please check the simple mail functionality it is working on your server(assuming that you are checking this functionality on server). You can only send mails from mail on live server. On local system it will not work.

Comment: Are you running it locally or online?

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST ['name'];` should be `$_POST['name'];` remove all the spaces in your post values.

so:

```
$name=$_POST ['name'];
$mobileno=$_POST ['mobileno'];
$email=$_POST ['email'];
$message=$_POST ['message'];
```

becomes:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
```

and like EternalHour said, it might be a good idea to validate if the form is filled in somehow; try this just after you declared `$name` and `$mobileno` etc;

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($mobileno) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)){
 // do stuff
}
```

the reason you would use `!empty()` instead of `isset()` is because isset would still return true if the form is submitted, since the values are set.. they are just empty.

**edit:**
further in your HTML change `action="get"` to `action="post"` in order to get it working.

Comment: I did that and there are no errors but I didn't receive mail, 

Do you think Html code is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the html in your question @IbnZiad?

Comment: in your html you set your form to `method="get"` change this to `method="post"`

Comment: it was "Post" but I changed it and still nothing.

Comment: @IbnZiad - No matter what you tried, if your method is get, then the php needs $_GET, if post then php is $_POST, to be safe for both, change $_POST to $_REQUEST, $_REQUEST can receive from either post or get

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `$_POST` variables, but I would recommend this instead so you will know if your POST succeeded.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$to = 'any mail.com';
$subject = ' Message from your Webite';
$msg = " Your name : $name\n"; 
$msg .= " Your Mobile No. : $mobileno\n"; 
$msg .= " Your email: $email\n" ;
$msg .= " Your Message: $message";

mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);

echo ' Thank You <br/>';
echo ' Your name ' . $name . '<br>';
echo ' Your email ' . $email . '<br>';
echo ' Your Mobile No. ' . $mobileno . '<br>';
echo ' Your Message ' . $message . '<br>';

?>

<br /><br />
 Here is the result from $msg: <br /><br />
 <?php 

 echo $msg;
} else {
echo "submit failed!";
exit;
}
?>
```

This way you know if there is no message your form submitted properly.

Comment: gets downvoted, downvotes me.. good job **EDIT:** also, wouldn't it be better to use !empty() because isset() will allways return true when a post is submitted.

Comment: Me neither, but he deserves it, you shouldnt use isset() because it would always return true after a form submittion. this isn't the awnser.

Comment: Oh wow, first you are posting a dupe awnser, then you downvote me because you get a downvote, and now you can't handle the truth and start flaming at me.

Comment: look at the post times again then please.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, if this is on a localhost, it wont work, cause mailfunction is disabled locally, you have to run it online*

Further: 
I dont see really where you are going wrong, but I took over my own mail function i got on my own website and converted it to yours

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){  // checks if the data from the submit button with the name send is here
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$mobileno=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mobileno']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$message=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['message']);

// you had spaces between your post variables which wont work. Also if you use mysqli, its better to play safe and make them safe, in case you do also database work. The variable $con is your connection information.

// echo out if your variables working. For example:
// echo $mobileno;
// this way you know for sure if the items are set.    

$message = wordwrap($message, 70); // in case its a long message, this allows 70 characters on one line
$to = 'any mail.com';   // your email
$subject = ' Message from your Webite';
$msg = " Your name : ".$name."\n"; 
$msg .= " Your Mobile No. : ".$mobileno."\n"; 
$msg .= " Your email: ".$email."\n" ;
$msg .= " Your Message:".$message ;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; // this has to do with css and html in your msg
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";  // this has to do with css and html in your msg
$headers .= "From: noreply@yourwebsite.com"; // change this to whatever you want it to come from

if (mail ($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo ' Thank You <br/>';
    echo ' Your name ' . $name . '<br>';
    echo ' Your email ' . $email . '<br>';
    echo ' Your Mobile No. ' . $mobileno . '<br>';
    echo ' Your Message ' . $message . '<br>';

// to make sure if your email is send it will output your message as given above, else an error
}else{
    echo ' Something went wrong ... oopsie daisy'; 
    } // closure of the if mail check
} // closure of the complete if(isset) check
```

dont forget to include your connection info as well for the mysqli function to sanitize your variables in case you re going to add it as well to a database. Also it's just a good practise to do it anyway. I defined $con as the connection info, yours might be different. You have to change it then to your connection variable.

if you use `mysql_` functions, use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['YourPostVariable']);` without the connection info. See here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

--edit--

updated it, because your message wouldn't output your variables, just the $name instead of the name within the $name variable.

Hope this helps, good luck debugging :)

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work and when I press send it turns to blank page.

Comment: You running this on a localserver, or online?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have just modified your code just a little bit..and I have recieved the email..please check with below code..please give your email in the textbox to recieve the email

```
<?php
if($_POST['email'] != '')
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    $to = $email;
    $subject = 'Message from your Webite';
    $msg = " Your name : $name\n"; 
    $msg .= " Your Mobile No. : $mobileno\n"; 
    $msg .= " Your email: $email\n" ;
    $msg .= " Your Message: $message";
    mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:'.$email);
    echo ' Thank You <br/>';
    echo ' Your name ' . $name.'<br>';
    echo ' Your email ' . $email .'<br>';
    echo ' Your Mobile No. ' . $mobileno . '<br>';
    echo ' Your Message ' . $message . '<br>';
}
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="justsend.php">

  <p>
    <label for="mobileno">your mobile</label>

    <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno">

    <label for="name"><br>
      your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">your email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="message">your message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="send">send msg</label>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```